# I need help in writing a subquery

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I have a query like this to create date series:

```
Select month
    From
    (select to_char(created_date, 'Mon') as Month,
           created_date::date as start_day,
           (created_date::date + interval '1 month - 1 day ')::date as end_day
    from generate_series(date '2021-01-26', 
                         date '2022-04-26', interval '1 month') as g(created_date)) AS "thang"
```

And the table looks like this:

| month |
| --- |
| Jan |
| Feb |
| Mar |
| Apr |
| May |
| Jun |
| Jul |
| Aug |
| Sep |
| Oct |

Now I want to count the `status` from the `KYC` table.

So I try this:

```
Select
    (Select month
    From
    (select to_char(created_date, 'Mon') as Month,
           created_date::date as start_day,
           (created_date::date + interval '1 month - 1 day ')::date as end_day
    from generate_series(date '2021-01-26', 
                         date '2022-04-26', interval '1 month') as g(created_date)) AS "thang"),
    count(*) filter (where status = 4) as "KYC_Success"
From kyc
group by 1
```

I hope the result will be like this:

```
Month |  KYC_Success
Jan   |      234
Feb   |      435
Mar   |      546
Apr   |      157
```

But it said

> error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

What should I change in this query?

Comment: The error message is quite correct, it isn't possible - in the select clause - to handle multiple rows from that subquery. You need to use that subquery in the `FROM` clause instead, but you have not supplied enough information. Something in the table KYC must relate to those months (probably a date or timestamp column) - what is that?

Comment: In Tbl KYC have column `Created_date` too, how should I change this subquery to correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that the table `KYC` has a timestamp column called `created_date` and the status column, and, that you want to count the success status per month - even if there was zero success items in a month.

```
SELECT thang.month
    , count(CASE WHEN kyc.STATUS = 'success' THEN 1 END) AS successes
FROM (
    SELECT to_char(created_date, 'Mon') AS Month
        , created_date::DATE AS start_date
        , (created_date::DATE + interval '1 month - 1 day ')::DATE AS end_date
    FROM generate_series(DATE '2021-01-26', DATE '2022-04-26', interval '1 month') AS g(created_date)
    ) AS "thang"
LEFT JOIN kyc ON kyc.created_date>= thang.start_date
    AND kyc.created_date < thang.end_date 
GROUP BY thang.month;
```

Comment: Yes, that what i want. But I try this but there is a error: syntax error at or near "ON"

Comment: Can u help me to explain the part kyc ON kyc.created_date>= thang.start_date
    AND kyc.created_date < thang.end_date. I dont get it. I know that u join table, but it like a clause, right?

Comment: You can ask another question as this is more than can be conveyed in a single comment. It will be helpful to supply sample data in such a question because it is how data is matched to that "on condition" that reslly matters here.